# Remote development - Edit on Windows & Build on Linux

Tags: linux, ide, makefile, clearcase

I am looking for a solution for a remote development environment as follows:
Editor - Windows Source Insight / Visual Studio
Source control - Clearcase
Build server - Linux
The above can't be modified.

In my current setup, I can view and edit the sources on Windows using a Windows Cleacase client.
My problem is mainly the build (and the later on, the debug) process.
I need to invoke 'make' from Windows on a specific Clearcase view on the Linux Server.
I can login in a separate process using SSH to the Linux server and run 'make', but it is a cumbersome procedure.
I am also unable to view the 'make' results and double-lick them to go to the specific warning/errors.

Is there any way to remotely bind a Windows command/batch to a Linux environment?
Perhaps through SSH?
Thank you for any suggestion you might have.

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is rather a pull strategy (where your build server fetches information on Linux, rather than trying to pilot everything from Windows.

If you follow the SSH path, be aware of [technote swg21351507](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21351507):

> **Linux SSH connection hangs when attempting to exit after starting ClearCase**.
>
> This can affect the use of scripts to start/stop ClearCase remotely using SSH.
>
> Cause
>
> This is a due to a OpenSSH server design, which will not close the console until all process/jobs executed by the user are completed.
>
> Refer to this [SSH FAQ](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/) for further details, regarding [background jobs](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/background-jobs.auto.html).
>
> Resolving the problem
>
> Redirect the ClearCase start script to either `/dev/null` or to a log file.
>
> Example:

```
/usr/atria/etc/clearcase start < /dev/null >& /dev/null
/usr/atria/etc/clearcase start < /tmp/ccstart >& /tmp/ccstart
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate regarding the "pull strategy"? How do I execute build command from Windows? and view the results?

Comment: @Amit: why from Windows? If you need to build on Linux, the pull strategy consist in a dynamic view on which a Linux script (job) periodically execute a 'cleartool lshistory' as seen in the comments of http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin in order to detect any new version checked-in since the last build. So you checkin from Windows, but detect the changes from Linux. No need for SSH there.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear... 
since I am using Source Insight (or Visual Studio) editor on Windows, I want to be able to invoke 'build' (+clean, etc) from Windows and receive the results in a normal 'results' window

Comment: @Amit: since I don't know Source Insight, is there any way to detect and build from Linux (as explained above), and send back the result file to Windows (through a shared Samba path for instance)?

Comment: Regarding the detect&build method - not really... we use several views simultaneously (each one is a different environment), and the build could invoked for either one of them.
Thus the results file depends on the actual view on which the build command was invoked.

Comment: @Amit: not a problem: you would have several dynamic views on Linux, each one with their jobs in charge of detecting new versions for each branch. You would create files with a specific names in order for your Editor on Windows to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try sshfs. I don't if there is a sshfs client for windows. If not, you can try NFS, or even SAMBA. Those definately work in Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this and wanted to answer, even if the original poster has surely resolved their issue.  This could be quite easily resolved by installing a jenkins instance on the build machine.  You could kick off the build from the web interface and have it pull the files from clearcase and tell you the results.